# How to use a user created function in n perl DBD::Oracle

Tags: oracle, perl, dbd

I have created a function in oracle 11g r2, I would like to call that function while inserting a record.

Following is my code block.

```
my $SQL="insert into sample values ( :sno, :amount , :func )";
my $sth =$dbh-> prepare($SQL);
$sth->bind_param(":amount" , $amount );
$sth->bind_param(":sno" , $i);

$sth->bind_param(":func" , my_func($amount)); 
$sth-> execute();
# I want the third parameter to be output of the function my_func.
```

Comment: Are you just missing the dollar sign before sth?  `sth->bind_param(":func" , my_func($amount));`

Comment: No way .. That line is incomplete am asking for suggestions. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $SQL = "insert into sample values (?, ?, my_func(?))";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);

$sth->execute($i, $amount, $amount);
```

Comment: I need to call the function my_func created by me in Oracle.

Comment: Could you please explain. That function is not a perl sub routine but a function created by me in oracle.

Comment: @NishanthLawrence `my_func` in `"insert into sample values (?, ?, my_func(?))"` is your plsql stored function.

Comment: I am using bind for one xmltype field so I cant mix the placeholder types here.